# Why is my function producing "invalid operands of types" error?

Tags: c++, function

I've created two functions that reference each other. My `round_to` function is supposed to round two floats to the nearest integer, and then my `modulo_round` function is supposed to reference that function and return floor(x * y) modulo p.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int round_to(float x, float y) {

    int sum = round(x*y);
    
    return sum;

}

int modulo_round(float x, float y, int p) {

    return floor(round_to(x, y)) % p;

}

int main() {

    cout << modulo_round(3.12, 3.45, 9);

}
```

But I'm getting an error that says: `error: invalid operands of types '__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<true, double>::__type' {aka 'double'} and 'int' to binary 'operator%'`

Can someone explain what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What are you expecting to accomplish by calling `floor()` on an integer?

Comment: What do you expect `floor` to do for a integral parameter? Note: the result of `floor` is a floating point value and the % operator doesn't work with those.

Comment: oh I see, so just remove the floor function then

Comment: cool error message. Its always interesting to see implementation details leaking :)

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes to your function modulo_round.

```
int modulo_round(float x, float y, int p) {

int sum = round(x*y);

int mod = sum % p;

return mod;
```

Hope this fixes the problem!